# PHP, drop down menu and search form, how to pass a variable to select a query

Tags: php, javascript, sql-server

I have spent over a week trying to get this working and I am stumped. So I have  drop down menu with 5 categories, I have a search form next to it where you can enter a keyword to search against a category. I want to have 5 queries which use a keyword to search against each of the categories using php and SQL server. How can I change the query to match the drop down selection? I was thinking passing a variable to php using JavaScript, but I am not the best programmer, and this idea was too much for me. so category one selected will mean the keyword entered into the search form will run query one etc...

Thank you.

Here is my query:

$term = $_POST['term'];

```
                                                    $tsql = "select * from personnel where SURNAME like '%" . $term . "%'";

                                                    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));

                                                    if( $stmt === false)
                                                    {
                                                         echo "Error in query preparation/execution.\n";
                                                         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                                                    }

                                                        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
                                                    {
                                                             echo 'NUMBER: '.$row['SNUM'];
                                                        echo '<br/> Jobtitle: '.$row['JOBTITLE'];
                                                        echo '<br/> Last Name: '.$row['SURNAME'];
                                                        echo '<br/> Manager: '.$row['MANAGER'];
                                                        echo '<br/> Sex: '.$row['SEX'];
                                                        echo '<br/> Join Date: '.$row['JOINDATE'];
                                                        echo '<br/> Division: '.$row['DIV'];
                                                        echo '<br/> Salary: '.$row['SALARY'];
                                                        echo '<br/> Bonus: '.$row['BONUS'];
                                                        echo '<br/><br/>';
                                                    }
```

My form:

```
<form  action="searchBar.php" method="post">
                                                        <input id="searchstyle" type="text" name="term" />
                                                        <input id="searchbutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
                                                    </form>
```

And the drop down menu:

```
<form name="myform" id="dropdown" action="dropsearch.php" method="POST">
                                            <select name="dropdownmenu">
                                                <option value="0" selected="selected">Select a category</option>
                                                <option value="Men">Men</option>
                                                <option value="Women">Women</option>
                                                <option value="Youth">Youth</option>
                                                <option value="Accessories">Accessories</option>
                                                <option value="Teamwear">Teamware</option>
                                            </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Paste some of your code here to see what you've got. Also errors!

Comment: Yes, show some code with how you're doing the vanilla search, without the categories.

Comment: Sorry I am trying to post code, and new to this site, it is causing me headache, I only so many characters. Not enough to sho wmy code :(

Comment: I apologise for how I posted the code, it also doesn't really show what I am trying to do, because I have not gotten that far, as I said I am not advanced enough to really do this, hence my initial post. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a form first of all with POST as method

Here is a good example:

```
<form name="myform" action="destination.php" method="POST">
<select name="mydropdown">
<option value="1">Fresh Milk</option>
<option value="2">Old Cheese</option>
<option value="3">Hot Bread</option>
</select>
</form>
```

In your *destination.php* file you will have to make a `switch` statement in order to see what value did you pass to your script.

```
switch ($_POST['mydropdown']) {
    case 1:
        $query = "first mysql query";
        break;
    case 2:
        $query = "2nd mysql query";
        break;
    case 3:
        $query = "3rd mysql query";
        break;
}
```

After that you will have to execute your query:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Note that this is a pretty simple way to do that and however you will have to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: It looks simple enough, I will try and implement your suggestions, I appreciate your help! will there be a big difference between mySQL and SQL Server? I am using the SQLSRV driver.

Comment: I suppose that SQL Server is the Microsoft Solution right? What is the system that you are running? Is it Windows server, is it a Linux machine, is a Win 7 with IIS?

Comment: It is Microsoft SQL server 2008 R2, using PHP and IIS on windows 7, I connect to my database using sqlsrv connect. I am struggling to find examples where sqlsrv is used, it always mysql :(

Comment: Why do you use php and IIS? I suppose you are developing something right now. When you are going to deploy it is going to be hard to reply this configuration on a hosting server.

Comment: Usually IIS works with ASP and SQL server. PHP works on Apache with Mysql most often. Of course there are some other types of server side languages and database architectures that you can link together in many ways, but IIS with PHP might not be a very good idea unless you have no other choice.

Comment: That is exactly my case, my university has set us with using Microsoft SQL server, IIS and PHP. Frustrating as hell!! The syntax is what is killing me, I usually find good examples on-line, but this scenario and set-up I am in is leaving me on my own mostly. The SQL for SQLSRV is different, trying some of the examples here is causing my code to stop working, I will need to work on converting this code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume you already have some way to send the keyword to the php script to perform the query. Simply send the category back as well.

If you are doing it via a form with a new pageload, give your `<select>` dropdown a name and it will be accessible via the `$_POST`, `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` (not advised) superglobal in php.

```
<form method="post" action="query.php">
    <input type="text" name="mykeyword" />
    <select name="mycategory">
        <option value="1" selected>category 1</option>
        <option value="2">category 2</option>
        <option value="3">category 3</option>
        <option value="4">category 4</option>
        <option value="5">category 5</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

In the php script:

```
$keyword = $_POST['mykeyword'];
$category = $_POST['mycategory'];   // values of 1 to 5
```

If you are doing it via AJAX, just include the value of the select element as one of your parameters.

Please post your code.

Comment: i know. but i don't know if he is using post or get. please remove your negative vote thanks... :(

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it has been noted and I will keep in my mind about sending the category back!

Answer (score 1):

Why javaScript?

Anyway, at a complete guess, your form will look something like this:

```
<form method="get" action="search.php">
  <select name="catId">
    <option value="1">Cat 1</option>
    <option value="2">Cat 2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="search" name="keyword" value="<?=$_GET['keyword']?>" />
  <input type="submit" name="submitFrm" value="Search" />
</form>
```

When submitted you'll wan to catch the keyword + category to do the search, e.g.

```
if (isset($_GET['submitFrm'])) {
  $keyword = $_GET['keyword'] // you'll want to clean get values before going into sql
  $catId = $_GET['catId']; // same here
  // build SQL query
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `searchable` WHERE `keyword` LIKE '%".$keyword."%' AND `catId`='".$catId."';
  // execute query
  // do your other stuff
}
```

But really without some idea of what your doing already it's hard to help. This is just an extremely basic example of what your trying to do.

Comment: This looks good, I will try and build my code from your examples, and see if I can figure it out! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey, looking at your code you've put in now - do the forms have to be separate? Or can you combine the two forms easily enough in the markup? If you can combine them, i'd do that. Otherwise you'd need to set a session variable for the category id, and then use that variable in your search script. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well I could do either, I used your example and put it all together, but now in the query part where I put in your code, it has made the code all greyed out, I a cannot see why there would be a problem, where can I post this code for you to see, up in my original post?

Thanks!